# A bug of the 2d layout engine of Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

If you add only one button in a whole new Activity, the screen looks like this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="false" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" ></Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

But if you add a ListView, then everything is OK:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/contactList"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="false" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" ></Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** This only happened in QVGA mode. HVGA mode worked fine.

Comment: Are you doing this on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Are you asking a question?  Or reporting a bug?  This is not the place to report bugs..

Comment: When I post this question, I didn't test it in HVGA mode and I don't know this is a bug.

Comment: could you please post the link to the bug report, if you made one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is.  This makes perfect sense.  In your first layout you used fill_parent on the linear layout and wrap_content on the button.

The button did exactly what it was supposed to.  It filled it's width and height using the width/height of the text inside as dictated by wrap_content.

If you are expecting the button to fill the whole screen, you need to use fill_parent on the actual view.

**Edit:**  Your code works perfectly fine for me in HVGA, QVGA, and WVGA.

[image]

Comment: Do you see, in the first image, the button looks ugly

Comment: only happend in QVGA, this really is a BUG!